# aws-cpp-sdk fails during Windows build due to install(EXPORT "foo-targets" ...) includes target "foo" more than once in the export set

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, aws-sdk-cpp

Asking so I can answer this myself, lost a day to it and want to save other folks the trouble.

Setup:

- Windows (seen on both Windows 10 and Server 2019)
- Visual Studio (seen on both Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019)
- cmake 3.19.0-rc1 (latest download as of this post)
- Following instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup.html for Windows build-from-source of the AWS C++ SDK.  Happens both for standard build from source and `vcpkg` alternative.  Also happens if you try to go build the "3rd party dependencies" mentioned at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp manually.

You try something like:

```
  git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git
  cd aws-sdk-cpp
  mkdir build
  cd build
  cmake ..
```

You get complaints from cmake ending:

```
  [...]
  Performing configure step for 'AwsChecksums'
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.17763.
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29112.0
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Configuring done
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : install(EXPORT "aws-checksums-targets" ...) includes target "aws-checksums" more than once in the export set. [C:\Users\xyz\aws-sdk-cpp\build\.deps\AwsChecksums.vcxproj]
  -- Generating done
  CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:224 (message):
  Failed to build third-party libraries.
```

There is a similar line reading `CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : install(EXPORT "aws-c-common-targets" ...) includes target "aws-c-common" more than once in the export set. [C:\Users\xyz\aws-sdk-cpp\build\.deps\AwsCCommon.vcxproj]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Completely non-obvious, but the issue appears to be with "cmake 3.19.0-rc1".  Changing to cmake 3.18.4 bypassed the issue.  I can't tell if this is a cmake issue or an sdk issue, or I'd be posting on somebody's github instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: I was unclear if marking your own answer as "accepted" was good practice, I have accepted it.

Comment: I found this issue also appears with cmake 3.19.1.

Comment: So glad you posted our experience. I have changed some things, including (but not only) CMake and this was the last thing I expected to cause problems.
Fixed going from 3.19.1 to 3.18.5.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I found out that the CMake that ships with Visual Studio 2019 16.9.1 is broken (version reported as `3.19.20122902-MSVC_2`).

I changed the path to CMake to point to that used by Vcpkg, which is version `3.19.2` and now it works just fine.

Therefore I assume the bug is in the CMake that ships with Visual Studio, and was fixed in 3.19.2.

Comment: I'm trying to install aws-sdk using vcpkg and I'm getting this error - vcpkg on Windows doesn't seem to have its own cmake? I have the same broken cmake version you mention.